# How can I plot these coin toss results in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm writing a script to represent a coin flipped 100 times and I want to plot the percentage of occurrences for "heads" as these 100 trials progress. I can't seem to get the plot to display the number of heads/trials versus trials 1 through 100. The plot shows all of the heads/trials at the 100 point on the x-axis.

This is the code I am using:

```
counter=0
wins=0
for k=1:100
    x=rand
    counter=counter+1
    if (x<0.5)
        x_coin=0
    else
        x_coin=1
        wins=wins+1    
    end
    B(k)=counter
    C(k)=wins
    fraction=C.*(1./B)
    plot(k,fraction)
end
```

Comment: If you want a pie chart, use that. if you want a 0=tails, 1=heads, and generate a list and scatterplot it that way, thats fine also. you cant just plot a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're storing the data you need in your vectors `B` and `C`, so there's no real reason to also call your plot command *within* your loop. Just make one plot after your loop is done.

Secondly, when you call [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html), you're passing your loop variable `k` as the first argument, and it only has a single value of 100 at the end of your loop. This is why all of your points in `fraction` are plotted at an x value of 100.

To get the plot you want, just do this *after* your loop:

```
plot(B,C./B);
```

Alternatively, you don't have to store the vector `B`. You could just do this after your loop:

```
B = 1:100;
plot(B,C./B);
```

Answer (score 7):

No need to loop here. Just

```
> n= 100;
> trials= 1: n;
> x= rand(1, n);
> C= cumsum(x< .5);
> plot(trials, C./ trials)
```

Comment: yup, exactly how MATLAB is intended to be used.